Building Sveltekit for cloudflare pages getting TypeError
I am trying to build my static website via vite build with the cloudflare adaptor.
My package.json is the following:
{
    "name": "my-website",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
        "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
        "lint": "prettier --check . && eslint .",
        "format": "prettier --write ."
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@iconify/svelte": "^4.0.2",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-cloudflare": "^0.0.1",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "^2.7.3",
        "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^3.0.0",
        "@types/eslint": "^8.56.7",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
        "daisyui": "^4.12.10",
        "eslint": "9.3.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte": "^2.36.0",
        "globals": "^15.0.0",
        "photoswipe": "^5.4.4",
        "postcss": "^8.4.39",
        "prettier": "^3.1.1",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.77.6",
        "svelte": "^4.2.7",
        "svelte-check": "^3.6.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.4.4",
        "tslib": "^2.4.1",
        "typescript": "^5.0.0",
        "typescript-eslint": "^8.0.0-alpha.20",
        "vite": "^5.0.3"
    },
    "type": "module"
}

Here is the error I get after building:

Using @sveltejs/adapter-cloudflare
error during build:
TypeError: builder.writeStatic is not a function
at adapt (file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/my-website/node_modules/@sveltejs/adapter-cloudflare/index.js:19:12)
at adapt (file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/my-website/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/core/adapt/index.js:38:8)
at finalise (file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/my-website/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/index.js:907:13)
at async Object.handler (file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/my-website/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/index.js:937:5)
at async PluginDriver.hookParallel (file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/my-website/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:20668:17)
at async Object.close (file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/my-website/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:21643:13)
at async build (file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/my-website/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BWSbWtLw.js:65466:17)
at async CAC.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/my-website/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:828:5)

Help how to fix this error is much appreciated!
I tried differend node, npm versions and tried to manually remove dependencies that I don't need, and that is so far the minimum I can work with. I am not sure from which dependency this arises and why.
I also tried different adaptors, with adapter-static and adapter-auto it works fine and I can execute a build successfully, however, not with adapter-cloudflare.
